# Touchbar Macbook Camera FOV

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

Had thought this camera spec would be easy to find online, but it seems FOV / field of view just isn't mentioned these days for macbook cameras?

Does anyone know what the touchbar macbook camera's FOV is? (Also Official link if that exists)

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any published specs, but according to a protractor and quick test it seems to be around 50º.

Comment: Horizontal, vertical or diagonal?